# How do I Add 2 GA4 instances to a website

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, event-tracking, google-analytics-4

I have a domain that has several sites sitting underneath it.

ie

```
My.domain.com/firstsite
My.domain.com/secondsite
My.domain.com/thirdsite
```

I have created new GA4 properties under a central account for each site. The GA4 is applied to the relevant pages via tag manager and the inbuilt GA4 tag, the trigger was the specific url of the page and everything is currently tracking as expected without issue.

I would like however to add an overriding GA4 account to collect the events for all pages.

Is this as simple as me adding another GA4 property to all pages or is there anything I need to mindful about.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to create seperate property for each site. You can add one property(or configuration) to each site.